# When is the attribute `isatty()` not present in sys.stderr?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dynamic, attributes

Sometimes this attribute is absent. (E.g., [this](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/issues/920) or [this](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/16659))
When does this happen? Is there a way to work around it? Can I just somehow add this attribute forcibly to make things run?

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that this only happens when `sys.stderr` is mocked or monkey-patched.

For instance, [the first GitHub issue](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/issues/920)  you refer to has the following error message:

```
AttributeError: 'UnicodeStdout' object has no attribute 'isatty'
```

This class, `UnicodeStdout`, is not in the standard library, and my research has pointed me to an old version of the [hachoir](https://pypi.org/project/hachoir/) lib (e.g. [this commit](https://github.com/vstinner/hachoir/commit/186f90c1cbebeffa0a8f990819a503e741db3fca#diff-34b8686d0ed892b31f8d494742237f97R69)).

The [second link](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/16659) has another suspicious error message, where the name of the class alone kind of indicates that `sys.stdout` was messed with:

```
AttributeError: '_StdoutProxy' object has no attribute 'isatty'
```

This class seems like a "proxy" that doesn't implement all methods of the original `sys.stdout`. This will not only affect `isatty()`, but potentially other attributes, like `fileno` (see [this other issue](https://github.com/google/rekall/issues/265) for example.)

You can monkey-patch the attribute yourself:

```
sys.stderr = SomeProxyClass()
```

or add a check, like:

```
if hasattr(sys.stderr, 'isatty') and sys.stderr.isatty()
```

but in most cases it should not be necessary.

Comment: How do I monkey-patch it?

Comment: @HappyFace added an example of how to monkey patch it. In this case you're need to implement the checks you want in `SomeProxyClass`, and probably then delegate the actual call to `stderr`.